# Need to add parameter values into text file in shell script

Tags: shell

I am trying to write a shell script which took value from parameter and place these values into text file and copy that text file from other server.

For ex if i pass abc in $1 and def $2 in parameter

It look like in text file like this 
a = something$1something
b= something $2 something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "a = something$1something" >> newfile
echo "b = something$2something" >> newfile
```

Comment: a = something$1something this is already available in text file i just want to put the value of $1 between text

Comment: the above suggestion will replace $1 / $2 variables with what was passed as parameters , and will append the lines to newfile. So if you put this in a script and call it like `script.sh one two` , the contents of newfile would be `somethingonesomething` `somethingtwosomething`